# How can I add force to an object relative to a game objects local position

Tags: unity-game-engine

Long story short, I'd like to projectile an egg in the chickens local -Y direction. I know how to add force to an object via AddForce (rb.AddForce(Vector3.Forward) etc...) but super stumped on how to add force to an object in local space, I feel like I'm really overthinking how to do this!

I've attached a gif for further context, hopefully this helps in what I'm trying to achieve here.

[image: Chicken Gif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the local axis of a transform in WorldSpace coordinates via the `Transform` component. In your case you want [`Transform.up`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-up.html)

```
rb.AddForce( - chicken.transform.up * force);
```

Comment: Wahey! Thanks! Super appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say that you can use:

```
rb.AddForce(-chicken.transform.right * force);
```

This can make an object move left or remove the negative sign to make it go right.